# Hotspot with Windows 7 starter

Tags: wireless-networking

I tried to share my wifi, but it does not work. Could I share Wi-Fi connection of Windows 7 Starter with other computers?

Thank you for your help.

P.s. I do it only with connectify, but this software is not free.

Comment: Take a look: http://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/

Comment: Hi @duDE, connectify is not free. Furthermore windows 7 starter has not the windows "Sharing" relative to wifi board.

Answer (score 1):

#### I tried to share my wifi, but it does not work.

> Windows 7 starter doesn't have Windows "Sharing" for WiFi

It was hidden. Try searching for `adhoc` in Start Menu Search.

Note:

- This loophole may be been fixed by a update, hotfix or service pack.

> Ad hoc wireless networking, which lets several Windows computers share a single connection, was one of several networking features Microsoft claims are not available in Windows 7 Starter.

...

> "To access the wizard that this link normally points to, simply Start Menu search for 'adhoc'."
>
> By searching for "adhoc" in Starter, then launching the executable, netbook users can create an on-the-fly connection for sharing an Internet connection.
>
> Rivera expects that Microsoft will close the loophole in a future update, hotfix or service pack. "I believe it's safe to assume this is an unintentional screw up."

Source [Wireless networking hidden in Windows 7 Starter](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2629046/microsoft-windows/wireless-networking-hidden-in-windows-7-starter.html)

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, I created ad hoc network, it appears on second computer, but it does not connect to this network.